# Find n if $\cos18°-\sin18°=\sqrt{n}\sin27°$

Tags: trigonometry

Find $n$ if $$\cos18°-\sin18°=\sqrt{n}\sin27°$$

I know this can be solved by directly substiuiting values of $\cos18°,\sin18°,\sin27°$ but is there a clever way to solve this question using trigonometric identities and minimal usage of using values from the table?

I tried taking $A=9°$ and solving but that is not helping much. Possibly it can be solved using complex numbers.Any hints??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\cos 18-\cos72=2\sin45\sin27$

Comment: i feel stupid after reading the solution. so simple Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

If you're taking the 'squaring-both sides' way of solving. Then,
$$\begin{align}n & =\left(\frac{\cos\left(18°\right)-\sin\left(18°\right)}{\sin\left(27°\right)}\right)^{2}\\ & =2\cdot\frac{1-2\cos\left(18°\right)\sin\left(18°\right)}{1-\cos\left(54°\right)}\\&=2\cdot\frac{1-\sin\left(36°\right)}{1-\sin\left(36°\right)}\\&=2\end{align}$$

Comment: thanks ,another method